# IOError Permission denied when using Google Drive API

Tags: python-2.7, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

Trying to get a script that writes to a Google sheet

The end of the traceback I get is

```
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", 
line 520, in __init__
self._context.load_verify_locations(ca_certs)
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

I followed the steps here at http://gspread.readthedocs.org/en/latest/oauth2.html

Not sure what's up.

```
__author__ = 'KirkLazarus'
import mechanize
import re
import gspread
import json
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials
#import bs4 

br = mechanize.Browser()

    pagelist=["https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesla_Model_S",
          "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chevrolet_Volt",
          "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesla_Roadster",
          "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nissan_Leaf",
          "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spark-Renault_SRT_01E",]
wheelbase = ''
length =''
width= ''
height =''

json_key = json.load(open('EVmodel-9d92f01d2cc0.json'))
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']

credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(json_key['client_email'],json_key['private_key'], scope)

gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)

wks = gc.open("EVModel").sheet1
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to run the code with sudo?